# C# Query an entity by using multiple parameters

Tags: c#, entity-framework

What am I doing wrong.  I get an error that says sequence has no arguements.

```
PumpSUM.tblcards card = ps.tblcards.First(p => (p.PinId == 1223 && p.CardId == 321));
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that this problem occurs when there is no first element to choose.You'd better use FirstOrDefault function.

Comment: Yes I agree with Gred, I would just add when you use FirstOrDefault if your query yields nothing, then FirstOrDefault will return null.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Take(1)` or `FirstOrDefault` instead.